# Looks like a Perl CGI bug

Tags: perl, popup, cgi

Perl version 5.8.5 I have:

```
my @dt = qw( 1 0 );
my %dt = qw( 1 single 0 multi );
my $val = 0;

$cgi->popup_menu( {
    -name    => "test",
    -default => $val,
    -values  => \@dt,
    -labels  => \%dt,
} )
```

Everything works fine in the popup, except "selected" is NEVER set.
So the first val is always chosen.

If I make a change, and change the 0 to 2 in all cases (`$val`, `@dt`, and `%dt`) then everything functions normally, and I get "selected" in the HTML tag.

Also I coped the code to Perl 5.8.8 box, and it works there *with* zeroes? Do I need to get our sysadmin to bump our Perl version on the 5.8.5 box?

Comment: FYI, using the HTML generation functions in CGI.pm is now [officially discouraged](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used). You should really be using a templating engine like Template Toolkit instead. Also, Perl 5.8.5 is *really* old (released in 2004); 5.24.0 was just released! Maybe you're stuck with this setup, but if you have any choice at all, update your toolset!

Answer (score 5):

You can update `CGI` independently from perl itself via CPAN.

It would be handy if you included the relevant use statements and module versions, as well as sample HTML output.

UPDATE: It looks like your version of perl should be using CGI 3.05 (see Module::CoreList). Checking the change log for CGI we find that this is a known bug.

> Version 3.45, Aug 14, 2009
>   [BUG FIXES]
>   3. Allow 0 to be used as a default value in `popup_menu()`. This was broken starting in 3.37. Thanks to Haze, who was the first to report this and supply a patch, and pfschill, who pinpointed when the bug was introduced. A regression test for this was also added. (RT#37908)

(They may not have dissected the (re)introduction of the bug correctly)

P.S. Rather than have a separate `@dt` simply set `-values` to `[ sort keys %dt ]`

Comment: I dont have root (corporate box) so I cant install perl.  My values arent always sorted , but nice tip could be handy... The code is on a windoze box so I couldn't copy to here, ... But the HTML is identical aside from the "selected" word missing when 0 is used. I've used Perl since 1996 and ever time I THOUGHT I saw a bug, it wasn't. But in this case its my only logical conclusion.  I googled "Perl build notes" to see if this problem was mentioned but no notes come up in the search.....

Comment: The general you. I was pointing out that it is not necessary to upgrade perl to upgrade a core module. Root isn't required either, since you can `require` a full path name to load a newer local copy; just one among many ways of doing that.

Comment: @belg4mit: `CGI` is no longer a core module anyway -- it has been deprecated and removed from the latest Perl distributions

Comment: @user3250422: Note that you don't need root access to install a Perl module. You may install it solely for your own use as long as you have the necessary tools. And I don't see why the source file being on a Windows system (please don't use derogatory names here -- it's supposed to be a professional platform) prevents you from posting it here. Surely, if you can read it then you can copy and paste it

Comment: if they had version 3.05 they wouldn't be affected by a bug the change log says was introduced in 3.37...

Comment: @ysth They must not be using 3.05. I downloaded it and I can't reproduce their issue.

Answer (score 3):

You may well be correct, and you are running an older version of the `CGI` module

What does `perl -MCGI -e 'print $CGI::VERSION, "\n"'` produce? And on the v5.8.8 system?

I am running version 4.28 of `CGI` and the result looks correct

```html
<select name="test" >
<option value="1">single</option>
<option selected="selected" value="0">multi</option>
</select>
```

You would probably benefit from an upgrade anyway, as even Perl v5.8.8 is well over ten years old, but you should be able to upgrade just the `CGI` module if it's easier. In fact the module is now deprecated and no longer a core module, so an upgrade to Perl v5.24 would have to be followed by the installation of `CGI` to regain the facility

The CGI functionality should never have been combined in the same module as the HTML generation, and even those who continue to use CGI (it is widely considered to have been superseded by PSGI) prefer to use separate modules like [`CGI::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Simple) or 
[`CGI::Minimal`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Minimal) together with 
[`HTML::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Tiny)
for generating the HTML

[**belg4mit** has identified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38210855/622310) that the bug you have found was fixed in version 3.4.5 of the `CGI` module, which was first released as part of Perl v5.11.0, a development version. The first subsequent public Perl release was v5.12, which contains version 3.4.8 of the module

Since you have found that an installation of Perl v5.8.8 doesn't display the problem, it is very likely that the `CGI` module has been upgraded on that machine independently of Perl

Comment: Trust me - if upgrading was an option we'd be very close to the latest, always. But in this company , its like impossible to get a unix admin to do anything for us. This is a JAVA/ORACLE business and they're always on the latest of everything. But if we ask for anything we're the red-headed step children...

Comment: It's just that you wrote *"Do I need to get our sysadmin to bump our Perl version on the 5.8.5 box?"*, so I assumed that it was a feasible solution. Don't forget that, as I said, you can install your own copy of CGI on your local machine and test using that

Comment: Is that the Java that [it looks like Oracle are killing off?!](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/07/how-oracles-business-as-usual-is-threatening-to-kill-java/) Stick with open-source!